# Open Shell Context/PopupMenu in my application

Tags: shell, winapi, popup

I write my own file explorer in SFML. I will create my own popup menu, but I think some people would like to use also the default options for items (folders, files, shortcuts). So one of the options in my popup menu will be the "Open default context menu here". But I don't know how to do that. I did some research and I read a lot of threads, articles, WinAPI documentation and other resources. I tried to simulate right-click in another window, I tried to simulate the Shift+F10 shortcut. Now I fight with menus. But I still have no results. 
I saw something like this in the file explorer that I used to.
There must be a solution to this.

I found this [Show system menu from another process (using WinForms, c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129218/show-system-menu-from-another-process-using-winforms-c)
But this activates standard windows menu (alt+space) but I want right-click menu (Shift+F10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't popup a file/folder's default right-click menu itself. But you can create your own menu and populate it with menu items relating to the file/folder, and invoke those items when clicked, by using the file/folder's own [`IContextMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu) interface.

In a nutshell, you obtain the `IContextMenu` for the desired file/folder, such as via [`IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getuiobjectof) or [`IShellItem::BindToHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler), and then you use the `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu()` method to populate your menu with items, and the `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand()` method to invoke commands from those items.

Raymond Chen wrote a series of articles on this very subject, which shows just how complex this task can be. There is too much information to post here.

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 1 – Initial foray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 2 – Displaying the context menu](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040922-00/?p=37793)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 3 – Invocation location](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040923-00/?p=37773)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 4 – Key context](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040924-00/?p=37753)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 5 – Handling menu messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040927-00/?p=37733)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 6 – Displaying menu help](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040928-00/?p=37723)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 7 – Invoking the default verb](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040930-00/?p=37693)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 8 – Optimizing for the default command](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041001-00/?p=37683)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 9 – Adding custom commands](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041004-00/?p=37673)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 10 – Composite extensions – groundwork](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041006-00/?p=37643)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 11 – Composite extensions – composition](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041007-00/?p=37633)